# What should be done about untagged questions?

Tags: discussion, support

I recently saw an [untagged](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) tag, supposedly created by [Community](https://korean.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community)

[One of our helpful users](https://korean.stackexchange.com/users/686/glorfindel) has proposed the following as tag wiki excerpt:

> This is a special tag that is designed to be used only by the system
>   for questions that have had all of their other tags removed. Do not
>   add this tag to existing questions, it is reserved for use by the
>   system to identify posts with no valid tags.

I had a look at the tag and 8 questions, even one [highly upvoted one](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/207/how-are-mathematical-symbols-read-in-korean), seem to be tagged with [untagged](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged), which is strange as I remember this particular question certainly had a relevant tag in the beginning (I can't remember what exactly the tag was though, sorry).

What is [untagged](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged), and what can we do about questions that have become [untagged](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged)?

Comment: Click on untagged above to see a list of questions. I have retagged a couple, but there are more remaining. We might need to create new tags for some of them.

Comment: Most of them have been retagged by now.

Comment: @Christophe Strobbe 3 left though

Comment: There should be only one left after the suggested edit queue has been cleared. I have no idea how to tag the question about speakers of Korean.

Comment: @Christophe Please have a look at the new discussion: https://korean.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174/should-we-have-a-korean-statistics-tag

Answer (score 3):

[untagged](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) is added to a post by the system under two circumstances.

1)  The post is migrated from another site and none of the tags it had before exist on the new site.

2)  The post had a tag that has been deleted by the Roomba, leaving it without any tags.

What should be done is to retag these questions with valid tags from this site.  If necessary, creating the tag(s).

Most sites on the StackExchange network will put in a tag wiki as you suggest - stating *Do not use* and giving these reasons.  However, there comes a catch.  If [untagged](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) itself gets swept up by the Roomba, the wiki disappears.  Then, when another post becomes untagged the wiki has to be replaced.