# Should we have a korean-statistics tag?

Tags: discussion

While cleaning up [untagged](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged), I came upon [this question](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/49/how-many-korean-speakers-are-there-world-wide), which has been well received so I think we should keep it. However, no one seems to know how to tag this question. I have thought of [korean-statistics](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/korean-statistics) for this and possible future similar questions, but I'm not sure if this is appropriate.

Does anyone have any ideas about a general, all encompassing tag for this, and other possible similar questions? What would we put in the tag wiki and excerpt, if we create it?

Only one suggestion per answer please.

Comment: I'm thinking "demographics", but I'm not a expert linguist.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm seems a good suggestion to me - perhaps you could add an answer so people can vote on it?

Answer (score 2):

Esperanto Stack Exchange has a similar question: [How many Esperanto speakers exist?](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/1/how-many-esperanto-speakers-exist) and they tagged it `[esperanto-speakers]`. A similar suggestion for this site would then be [korean-speakers](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/korean-speakers). It's easier to think of (when submitting new questions etc.) than [geolinguistics](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geolinguistics).

Comment: I like this idea - +1! Only concern I'd have is that it could be too widely-interpreted - some people might think that pretty much *every* question about Korean could be labelled `korean-speakers`.

Answer (score 1):

According to [thefreedictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/geolinguistics), **geolinguistics** is

> the study of the geographical distribution of languages

It could be a suitable (though fairly specific) tag for questions in this area.

Comment: Why not just "Linguistics"?  The linked question doesn't ask about geographical distribution and the tag would have a wider use.

Comment: @Chenmunka I guess 'linguistics' on its own doesn't suggest to me that it could be used for questions that weren't about the structure or evolution of the language itself...

Answer (score 1):

The tag should be **Demographics**. That describes statistical information about speakers of Korean.